# Clear Button ng-click not triggering event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following code and ng-click is not working for the clear button. It just closes the dropdown menu. What might be the reason?

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 borderAtRight" 
     
    <!--  Dropdown and Menu -->
    <div class="btn-group topFilterCtrl filterDropdn" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body id="ddlStatus">
 <div id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary panelTextFont14 noBorder" dropdown-toggle> Status 
        <span class="caret caretSpan"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownLabel" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" ng-show="!vm.showthis">
 <div class="customScroll">
     <li role="menuitem" class="changeColorOnHover" ng-repeat="optionThis in vm.List track by $index" ng-show="list.value != null">
  <a href="#">
      <div class="checkbox" id="{}index}" ng-show="this.value != null" ng-click="vm.applyFilterForResultCount()" ng-change="vm.getCount(this)" ng-model="this.flag">
                 <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.clickStatusCheckBox(this);$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="this.value != null" />
    {{this.value}}
   </label>
      </div>
  </a>
     </li>
 </div>
        <!--Clear div-->
        <li role="menuitem" class="btn btn-default buttonli" ng-click="vm.clearAll()">
     <a href="#">
                <p>
                    <span class="clearAllBtn">Clear</span>
            <span class="dropDownBtnItem">  – All </span>
         </p>
     </a>
 </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```css
function clearAll() {
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.list.length; i++) {
                if (vm.list[i].flag === true) {
                    vm.list[i].flag = false;
                    vm.listFilterCount -= (vm.list[i].value.length + 3);
                }
            }
            
            vm.listFilterS = '';
            vm.count= ' ';
            vm.include= [];
            vm.list= [];
        }
```

ng-click="vm.clearAll()" is not working and hence not clearing checkbox.

Comment: @smitha I am not able to find any script part in your posted code. post some JavaScript code

Comment: Added it. More than my JS, I feel something is happening on default jQuery event bubbling. Need to prevent But not sure how